# How to successfully make candied ginger?

Tags: sugar, candy, ginger

I tried to make candied ginger from fresh roots, but the result didn't turn out like I was expecting.

The recipe I followed had me simmer the slices of ginger in a saucepan with 1 1/2 cups of brown sugar melted in water, for 35 minutes.

Then I leaved the slices to dry on a drying rack overnight. Then I rolled the pieces in sugar to coat them (I found the recipe online).

The result I was expecting to get is something very candied, almost transparent, like this piece (bought in a store):

[image]

what I actually ended up getting was much darker and the sugar didn't stick to the pieces at all:

[image]

It still tastes quite good, but it isn't as sweet as the one from the store, and didn't look quite as good.

I would love to know how to salvage this batch, or have more tips on  successfully candying ginger to a perfect result next time.

Answer (score 1):

Boiling the ginger will help to make the ginger less spicy - the longer,the less spicy. I like my ginger with more of a bite, so I boil it for only 10 minutes. Then strain it through a collander, the way you would a pot of boiled pasta. Put the ginger back into the pot with equal portions of sugar and water - enough to fully cover the ginger - and boil to 225F. Lift the ginger out of the syrup with a slotted spoon and place it on a cooling rack. Coat in sugar. For greater detail, see this link: http://www.makeitlikeaman.com/2013/12/07/candied-ginger-2/

Answer (score 0):

35 min simmer in sugar sounds a bit long. You should try and simmer the ginger slices in water first for 35min and then remove the water that is left from the pan. Then add the sugar and boil until 225 degrees F, using a candy thermo. Remove the ginger from the pan. The ginger should be sticky enough then for the sugar coating to stick.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand "remove the water / add the sugar" add the sugar to what?

Comment: Just edited the awnser now.

Comment: So in step 2 I just have sugar in the pan, but no water?

Comment: No. Sugar and ginger, there should be enough moisture left to go around to get the mix to a nice boil.

Comment: here is a similar way of how I explained http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Crystallized-Ginger

Answer (score 0):

I found a recipe that peels and slice the ginger.  Coat it with a liberal amount of sugar overnight or at minimum 4 hours.  Cook the ginger and sugar (with the syrup developed) over medium heat until the sugar begins to crystalize.  This is the best outcome I have ever had.  I don't bother to boil and drain.  I like it very spicy.

Phyllis